# Определить отсутствие игрока на странице и послать запрос на обновление статуса

Tags: javascript, ajax, разработка-игр, javascript-events

Тренируюсь на `javascript`, создаю онлайн игру. Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо обновлять статус игрока, когда он отсутствует на странице (не активный игрок).
Пробовал использовать события `beforeunload` и `unload`. Поделитесь опытом, возможно есть другой способ отправлять запросы об отсутствии игрока

```
addEventListener('unload', (event) => {
    /**
     * Send notify of your absence in room.
     */
    $.post("/ajax/player/update", {
        userID: window.user.id,
        roomID: window.room.id
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать проще: установить какой-то промежуток времени, после которого игрок считается оффлайн. Например 20 минут бездействия.

При этом установить список действий, при котором обновляется статус на онлайн: написал сообщение в чат, ударил кого-то, вошёл в бой, вошёл в ЛК и т.д. Получается при таком действии идёт запрос на операцию, одновременно обновляет статус на онлайн и одновременно начинается новый отсчёт на то, чтобы юзера считать AFK

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и он решает мою проблему. Хотел бы узнать какая будет нагрузка на сервер каждый раз отправлять запрос на обновление статуса каждого игрока и проверять игроков на прошедший пробежуток?